# Interesting integral in changing integration bounds - sum

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{\frac{1}{k^3}}^{\frac{1}{k^2}} e^{- \left ( x^2 + |x| \right) } ~~ dx$$

How do I even begin calculating this horrifying thing?! I mean, I get the idea of the bounds being smaller and smaller thus making sense of this sum.. first I thought to myself that maybe we just need to find the integral itself, plug the bounds $\frac{1}{k^2}$ and $\frac{1}{k^3}$ and then take the sum (running on the variable $k$ of course) - but then what? It seems impossible! Is there another way of doing it?

This seems like a really hard problem for me, I would appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: $$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \int_{\frac{1}{k^3}}^{\frac{1}{k^2}} e^{-x^2-x} \, dx=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2} \sqrt[4]{e} \sqrt{\pi } \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{k^3}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\approx 0.472$$

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just too long for comments. Well, we can at least reduce it a bit using the normal distribution...

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k \ge 1 }\int_{1/k^3}^{1/k^2}e^{-(x^2+|x|)} dx = & \sum_{k \ge 1 }\int_{1/k^3}^{1/k^2}e^{-(x^2+x)} dx
 = e^{1/4} \sum_{k \ge 1 }\int_{1/k^3}^{1/k^2}e^{-(x-1/2)^2} dx\\
  = &  e^{1/4} \sqrt{\pi} \sum_{k \ge 1} (\Phi(1/k^2)-\Phi(1/k^3))
\end{align*}

where $\Phi$ is the normal distribution with mean $\frac 12$ and standard deviation $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$.